# Printing values after a cast to a byte array

Tags: c, arrays, casting

I'm trying to understand how to debug data that has been serialized into a byte array. The code shows stripped down problem with failed solution trials.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get a print of the whole array member `12345678` insted of just `78`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t words[2] = {0x12345678, 0x87654321};
    char * struct_array = &words;

    printf("%x \n", *struct_array);   //  78   prints a lsb byte from the first array member
    printf("%lx \n", *struct_array);   // 78   assuming it would print more than a single byte

    //Perhaps it's printing a single byte because of the char pointer.
    printf("%x \n", (uint32_t) *struct_array);   // 78
    printf("%lx \n", (uint32_t) *struct_array);  // 78
    // Nope
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
char * struct_array = &words;
```

makes `struct_array` into a pointer to `char`. De-referencing that will give you a `char`, you can't change that *after* the fact by casting.

You can of course cast the pointer before dereferencing (but risk undefined behavior):

```
printf("%x\n", *(uint32_t *) struct_array);
```

It's of course better to use the proper de-serializing code, and not attempt to brute-force it by pointer dereferencing trickery. If you have a bunch of bytes that you know represent a larger number, just put it together yourself.

To expand on the last point, if this had been an actual array of bytes:

```
const uint8_t data[] = { 0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12 };
```

and you wanted to re-assemble those into a 32-bit unsigned integer, assuming little-endian storage you'd do:

```
const uint32_t x = data[0] | (data[1] << 8) | (data[2] << 16) | (data[3] << 24);
printf("x de-serialized into 0x%08x\n", x);
```

That would print `x de-serialized into 0x12345678`, and all of this without violating anything. :)

Comment: `If you have a bunch of bytes that you know represent a larger number, just put it together yourself.` What would that mean in the given example?

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer Added more code to show that point in more detail.

Comment: @unwind This way of deserialising is independent of endianess. However, the `data[n] `are cast to `int`, so there could occur a signed integer overflow with `data[3] << 24`.

Answer (score 2):

`struct_array` is of type `char*`, i. e. a pointer to char. `*struct_array` then dereferences to a single `char` (a single byte), so only the first byte in memory occupied by `words` is looked at. You get 0x78, because obviously your machine is a little endian one, so data is stored in inverse byte order. Casting a `char` back to `uint32_t`won't change anything about that - the value is 0x78, it fits into the 32-bit integer, so it stays 0x78.

If you want to get the whole value, you need to read the whole value, i. e. dereferencing a pointer to `uint32_t`, which means that you need to cast the pointer before dereferencing it:

```
*(uint32_t*)struct_array
```

Comment: `*(uint32_t*)struct_array` is unfortunately a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: @Lundin How? It is just casting back to the original type with the original address (as there has never been a value added to the pointer)...

Comment: @Lundin `struct_array` is a `char *` so strict aliasing rules don't apply.

Comment: @IanAbbott no, you're wrong there, it's the other way around. but this is not UB, since it's casting back to original type.

Comment: @Aconcagua I was assuming that the OP wanted to actually do something with the character array, or there would be no point in converting to char in the first place. Regardless, "manually" keeping track of the effective type is dangerous. If you don't know what the effective type is, then it will be very easy to write bugs this way.

Comment: @IanAbbott Converting from "something" to a character type is fine, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

```
//expected it would print more than a single byte
```

That expectation is wrong. The dereference has already been made, and at that time, `struct_array` was of type `char *`. The value then (promoted), is used as the argument to the conversion specifier.

To emphasize, the type of argument supplied and  the conversion specifier are not *internally related* as you might have expected, it's the job of the programmer to get both of these aligned.

If you want the buffer to produce the original value as of the source type, you need to use a cast to get the pointer chaged to the actual type, and then, dereference that to obtain the value. After dereference, the cast makes no sense here.

*Word of caution: you can only cast the pointer back to the original type or compatible type thereof, not just "any" other type, that would break strict aliasing*.

Comment: And the reason for DV?

Comment: Seriously, this is not an answer, but a comment. Please VtC as unclear if the question is not clear.

Comment: @Olaf OK...I thought it was a problem with the _expectation_. Just providing a _longer_ width conversion specifier or trying to cast the value does not get more _bytes_ while dereference.

Comment: If I understood it wrong...that's my fault, agree, but till time..aforesaid comment is my understanding.

Comment: Was assuming that printf would take as much data it needs to print a `%lx` regardless of what the type is.

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer There you go wrong....it's not the case. printf will only convert the supplied argument according to supplied conversion specifier. The argument value, you'll get by dereferencing, which does not depend on supplied conversion specifier.

Comment: To be a little more precise: printf *does* take as much data as needed to print a `%lx` - but it takes them from the arguments you pass to it. If you dereference a `char*`, you get the value of a single byte. If you then cast this value to a larger type, the value must remain the same, so the additional more significant bytes are simply filled with zero bytes...